# Stop animation from playing on pageload

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a webpage that is designed with a hideaway menu on the left hand side.  I am using CSS animations to make the menu slide out smoother when the div is hovered over.  However, the animation that smooths the div sliding back out of view plays when you load the page up.  Is there any way that I can bypass this?  Thanks in advance!

Link to testing page so you can see what it's doing:  http://testing.justinwidener.x10.mx/

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="scene">
        <aside class="mainmenu">
            <span class="hide-show">»</span>

            <div class="mainmenu_content">
                <img class="mainmenu_img" src="images/logo.png" />

                <hr class="mainmenu_hr" />

                <div class="mainmenu_nav">
                    <a href="index.html">WORK</a> /
                    <a href="contact.html">ABOUT</a>
                </div>

                <hr class="mainmenu_hr_divider" />

                <div class="mainmenu_contact">
                    <img src="images/iconLink.png" /> <a href="contact.html">Contact me!</a><br />
                    Serving the Junction City, KS area.<br />
                    Contact Hours:<br />
                    Mon-Fri --- 10am to 9pm<br />
                    Sat --------- 12pm to 8pm<br />
                    Sun -------- NO CONTACT PLEASE
                </div>

                <hr class="mainmenu_hr_divider" />

                <div class="mainmenu_viewon">
                    <img src="images/comp_icon&32.png" /><img src="images/viewontext.png" /><img src="images/phone_touch_icon&32.png" />
                </div>

                <hr class="mainmenu_hr_divider" />

                <div class="mainmenu_contact_info">
                    <img src="images/globe_2_icon&16.png" /> <a href="www.justinwidener.com">www.justinwidener.com</a><br />
                    <img src="images/phone_2_icon&16.png" /> (785) 375-3066<br />
                    <img src="images/mail_icon&16.png" /> j-w-designs@outlook.com<br />
                </div>

                <div class="mainmenu_footer">
                    ©2015. All rights reserved. V.1.0.
                </div>
            </div>
        </aside>


        <div class="maincontent">

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.scene {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
/*SCROLLBAR */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: #fff;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #333;
}

/* MAIN MENU */
.mainmenu {
    height: 100%;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #FFFFCC;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -325px;
    -webkit-animation: mainmenuout linear .5s;
    animation: mainmenuout linear .5s;
}
.mainmenu:hover {
    left: 0px;
    -webkit-animation: mainmenu linear .5s;
    animation: mainmenu linear .5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes mainmenuout {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: -325px;}
}
@keyframes mainmenuout {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: -325px;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes mainmenu {
    from {left: -325px;}
    to {left: 0px;}
}
@keyframes mainmenu {
    from {left: -325px;}
    to {left: 0px;}
}
.mainmenu_hr {
    border: thick solid #1a171b;
}
.mainmenu_content {
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.mainmenu_contact {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.mainmenu_contact_info {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

.mainmenu_nav {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.mainmenu_hr_divider {
    border: 1px solid #1a171b;
}
.mainmenu_viewon {
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;
}
.hide-show {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    padding-right: 7px;
}
.mainmenu_footer {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```